# Экранирование кавычек в JS

Tags: javascript, экранирование

Почему так не работает?

```
onMouseOut="setTimeout('alert(\"You went away from me\")', 1000);"
```

А так работает?

```
onMouseOut="setTimeout('alert(\'You went away from me\')', 1000);"
```

Comment: Если это написали вы, не делайте так больше, пожалуйста

Comment: @tutankhamun, если честно, то моя "конструкция". А как тогда сделать задержку срабатывания скрипта?

Comment: @RussCoder, Хотя бы потому что - http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onmouseout.

Comment: Хорошей практикой является вынесение JavaScript-кода в отдельный тег `<script>`, а если кода много, то вообще в отдельный js-файл. Это отделение "мух от котлет", которое при поддержке сайта сильно экономит нервы и время.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что это html-разметка и вместо кавычек надо писать `&quot;`:

```
onMouseOut="setTimeout('alert(&quot;You went away from me&quot;)', 1000);"
```

Но вообще, так делать не надо.

---

Проблема именно в html-разметке. Если попытаться выполнить такое же присваивание в джаваскрипте, то первый код корректен, а второй - нет (экранируется апостроф, в строке остаётся апостроф и результат кривой - надо `\\'`). Но у html правила экранирования другие и обратный слеш оказывается во внутренней строке, не оказывая влияния на значение атрибута. Именно поэтому вторая строка корректна, а первая преждевременно кавычкой закрывает атрибут.

PS: а имена атрибутов-событий по правилам пишутся полностью маленькими буквами.

---

```js
function test1() {
  eval("console.log('\'text\'')"); // Это текст из правильного варианта - тут такое не годится
}

function test2() {
  eval("console.log(\"'text'\")"); // Экранируются символы во внешней строке, не экранируется во внутренней
}

function test3() {
  eval("console.log('\\'text\\'')"); // Чтобы экранировать апостроф во внутренней строке надо экранировать сам обратный слеш во внешней
}
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: .25em;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="console.log("'text'")">Неправильно</button>
<button onclick='console.log("'text'")'>Тоже неправильно</button>
<br>
<button onclick="console.log(&quot;'text'&quot;)">Правильно</button>
<button onclick='console.log("&#39;text&#39;")'>Тоже правильно</button>
<button onclick="console.log(&quot;&#39;text&#39;&quot;)">И это правильно</button>
<br>
<button onclick="console.log('\'text\'')">Правильно с экранированием</button>
<br><br>
<button onclick="test1()">Неправильно в js</button>
<br>
<button onclick="test2()">Экранирование внешних в js</button>
<button onclick="test3()">Экранирование внутренних в js</button>
<br><br>
<button onclick=console.log("'text'")>Ну и напоследок - так можно</button>
```

Comment: А как тогда надо? Я в JS не часто программирую. Так как тогд сделать, что бы скрипт после увода мышки сработал через определённое время? (У меня ToolTip, надо что-бы юзер успел на него наехать, после съезда мышки с объекта на него.)

Comment: @I_CaR, в скрипт подписку на событие (через addEventListener) и в setTimeout передавать не строку, а функцию. А конкретно задержку скрытия можно сделать вообще на css.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что кавычки для экранирования не должны быть подобны кавычкам переменной. То есть если `var variable = ""`, то внутри должно быть **'text'**, чтобы экранирование 'text' выполнялось(и наоборот).
В Вашем же случае этот код будет:

```
onMouseOut='setTimeout("alert(\"You went away from me\")", 1000);'
```

Comment: Уже раз 5 перечитал - так и не понял, что ты хотел сказать. И в любом случае, проблема вообще не в этом.

Comment: Не понял, что я хотел сказать, и уверен, что проблема не в этом о_О

Comment: Потому что проблема именно в html-разметке. Если попытаться скормить присваиваемую часть в eval, то первый код корректен, а второй - нет (экранируется апостроф, в строке остаётся апостроф и результат кривой - надо `\\'`). Но у html правила экранирования другие и обратный слеш оказывается во внутренней строке, не оказывая влияния на значение атрибута. Именно поэтому вторая строка корректна, а первая преждевременно кавычкой закрывает атрибут. Ты про это вообще ничего не сказал, а сказал что-то не сильно понятное про объявление переменных в js.

Comment: Ок, тогда найди отличие между `alert("'text'")` и `alert(""text"")` и перечитай то, что я написал, тогда поймешь, что я пытался донести до автора.

Comment: Это-то тут при чём? Первая конструкция выводит `'text'` вместе с апострофами, а вторая некорректна.

Comment: Что и требовалось доказать. Правильно или `alert("'text'") // 'text'` или же `alert('"text"') // "text"`. Мы с тобой говорим об одном и том же.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/36ndtu23/