# Почему атрибут value у тега <option> заполняется пустым значением?

Tags: javascript, html, knockoutjs

Пытаюсь с помощью binding Knockout`a заполнить атрибут value у тега option. 
Значение атрибута получается пустым. Прошу указать ошибку.

https://jsfiddle.net/Elder27/w4jLowqx/

```js
var viewModel = {
  phones: ko.observableArray([{
    name: "iPhone SE",
    id: 111
  }, {
    name: "Lumia 950",
    id: 222
  }, {
    name: "Zenfone 3",
    id: 333
  }])
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select id="select1" data-bind="options: phones, optionsText: function(item){return (item.name + ':' + item.id);}, value: function(item){return item.id+""}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> data-bind="... value: function(item){return item.id+""}"
> ```

```
data-bind="... optionsValue: function(item){return item.id}"
```

1. С кавычками косяк: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456039/178988
2. `optionsValue`, а не `value`

```js
var viewModel = {
  phones: ko.observableArray([{
    name: "iPhone SE",
    id: 111
  }, {
    name: "Lumia 950",
    id: 222
  }, {
    name: "Zenfone 3",
    id: 333
  }])
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select id="select1" data-bind="options: phones, optionsText: function(item){return (item.name + ':' + item.id);}, optionsValue: function(item){return item.id}">
```

Comment: спасибо.  какая глупая ошибка оказалась